# Why is IntelliSense not recognizing my query selected item as an element?

Tags: javascript, html, css, visual-studio-code, intellisense

## Problem

I am trying to figure out why VSCode's IntelliSense won't suggest element object properties when I access an HTML element with:

```
document.querySelector();
```

Whenever I use the `document.querySelector()` method and then use the `.` operator to attempt to see the properties of my selected element, I don't get a list of CSS properties such as `style`

## Example

I have a div element in my HTML file with the class 'list'

```
<div class='list'>
```

And in my .js file I am able to access this element by writing:

```
const listElement = document.querySelector('.list');
```

My problem is that when using the `.` operator on `listElement`, VSCode does not show basic properties such as `style`. I am still able to set things by manually typing something like

```
listElement.style.display = 'none';
```

but when I use the `.` operator VSCode does not suggest `style` and when I type style and use the `.`operator again it does not suggest `display`. My question is:
**How can I get Intellisense to display these properties?**

*Note: I am new to HTML, CSS, and Javascript so I don't know if I'm using all the correct terminology, but I tried!*

Comment: I guess because querySelector can return null, so VSCode is not so flexible as Web Storm for example, it doesnt suggest methods if it is not sure about type

Comment: Try using [TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/) instead: `const listElement: HTMLElement = document.querySelector('.list');` This way VS Code can easily determine which properties to show.

Comment: Have you tried using `ctrl + space` thats usually the combination for intellisense to display.

Comment: highly related: [Why is the style property suggested by TypeScript for the result of document.getElementById(), but not document.querySelector()?](/q/75640206/11107541)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

VS Code's JavaScript IntelliSense does not know what your HTML looks like so it will assume that `querySelector` returns a very generic type of object. That's why you don't see suggestions for `.style` and some other common DOM properties. Those properties really may not exist on what `querySelector` returns!

However you can explicitly tell VS Code the type of the element that `querySelector` returns with a simple [JSDoc type annotation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-checking-javascript-files.html#type):

```js
/** @type {HTMLDivElement} */
const listElement =  document.querySelector('.list');
```

This should give you proper IntelliSense:

[image: Example of IntelliSense on HTML div element after the type has been declared.]

Comment: yeah your answer worked for me. replaced the queryselector with getElementById and it showed me what I desired