# Why does vscode not give me style option when it is available?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, autocomplete

I am typing here and trying to edit the style of an element in JS:

[image: Me editing style in JS]

For some reason, I don't get the style property, but when I type everything manually, everything works fine. Would appreciate an answer as this is pretty confusing.

EDIT: Some people say that this never works. That isn't true.

[image: Me actually getting style access]

Comment: Those recommendations won't work when you are styling with the help of JS. Once you type you will get them, as you are getting now.

Comment: That isn't true. This has worked before for me - it just isn't working now

Comment: How are you getting the `message` element?  That is important to show.  Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/58423796/836330.

Comment: I made a ```message``` variable which is equal to ```document.querySelector('.message')```. Autocomplete works on all other elements like this, but not this one.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but this doesn't answer my question, as vscode is giving me lots of options, but not the _style_ option. Also, this issue is simply with the ```message``` element, but not with any other elements, although I only use ```querySelector()``` in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this code:

```js
const el = document.querySelector(".myclass");
const el2 = document.querySelector("h1");
```

and this hover info about the type of `el` and `el2`:

[image: query selector return demo].

In the first case `.myClass`, a class can be added to any Element and so vscode (perhaps the Typescript language service providing the hover and completion information) cannot determine what kind of an Element it is and simply returns `Element` object.  Now `Element` has a lot of properties but not `style`.  See [MDN: Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element)

In the second case above `h1` the language service can infer that the returned object is an `HTMLHeadingElement` which does have a `style` property.

If you want the completion information for the first `.someClass` example you have to give the completionProvider a hint and that can be done like this:

```js
/** @type {HTMLDivElement} */
const el = document.querySelector(".myclass");
```

Now hover over `el` and you will get `HTMLDivElement` and `style` completion option.